# crear List o Map sin valores repetidos en flutter

Tags: lista, flutter, map

Buen dia una consulta me hice bolas al querer realizar lo siguiente tengo esta estructura

```
Data = [
    {"id" : 1, "nombre" : "A", "cantidad" : 20},
    {"id" : 1, "nombre" : "A", "cantidad" : 30},
    {"id" : 2, "nombre" : "B", "cantidad" : 15},
    {"id" : 2, "nombre" : "B", "cantidad" : 10},
    {"id" : 3, "nombre" : "C", "cantidad" : 20}]
```

Quiero obtener este resultado solo de los id sin duplicar

`R=[{"id" : 1}, {"id" : 2}, {"id" : 3}]` o

```
R = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sencillo, de la forma larga:

```dart
  final data = [
    {"id": 1, "nombre": "A", "cantidad": 20},
    {"id": 1, "nombre": "A", "cantidad": 30},
    {"id": 2, "nombre": "B", "cantidad": 15},
    {"id": 2, "nombre": "B", "cantidad": 10},
    {"id": 3, "nombre": "C", "cantidad": 20}
  ];

  Set<int> ids = {};
  for (Map item in data) {
    ids.add(item['id']);
  }
  final idsArray = ids.toList();
  print(idsArray);
```

De la forma corta:

```dart
  final data = [
    {"id": 1, "nombre": "A", "cantidad": 20},
    {"id": 1, "nombre": "A", "cantidad": 30},
    {"id": 2, "nombre": "B", "cantidad": 15},
    {"id": 2, "nombre": "B", "cantidad": 10},
    {"id": 3, "nombre": "C", "cantidad": 20}
  ];

  final idsArray = data.map((item) => item['id']).toSet().toList();
  print(idsArray);
```

El truco está en usar `toSet()` para que añada los elementos sin repetir.

Más info : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set-class.html

Comment: Genial muchas gracias, algo asi estaba buscando